# Problems in a regular expression to extract names using stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I cannot fully understand why my regular expression does not work to extract the info I want. I have an unlisted vector that looks like this:

```
   text <- c("Senator, 1.4balbal", "rule 46.1, declares",
             "Town, 24", "A Town with a Long Name, 23", "THIS IS A DOCUMENT,23)
```

I would like to create a regular expression to extract only the name of the "Town", even if the town has a long name as the one written in the vector ("A Town with a Long Name"). I have tried this to extract the name of the town:

```
   reg.town <- "[[:alpha:]](.+?)+,(.+?)\\d{2}" 
   towns<- unlist(str_extract_all(example, reg.prov))
```

but I extract everything around the ",".

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the expected output for the `text` you provided? How can you identify a town name (what are the requirements)?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `str_extract(text, "^\\p{Lu}[\\s\\p{L}]*")`? Can each vector item contain only one town?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a town name starts with a capital letter (`[[:upper:]]`), ends with a comma (or continues to the end of text if there is no comma) (`[^,]+`) and should be at the start of the input text (`^`). The corresponding regex in this case would be:

```
^[[:upper:]][^,]+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QXYtyv/1

Comment: Thanks! you got what I mean. However, for whatever reason, I do not obtain the names of the towns from my document. I obtain characters that look like the last one in my vector in my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I have solve the problem thanks to @Dmitry Egorov 's demo post in the comment. the regular expression is this one `([[:upper:]].+?, [[:digit:]])`

Thanks for your quick replies!!

Comment: Please check my answer, I believe it is a better option since it shows how to use a base R function to get the matches you need.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but Dmitry's link was really usefull for other projects that I have done =)

Comment: BTW, see [`\b\p{Lu}[^,]++(?=, \d|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/CYSMS2/1). It might even be a better pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following regex:

```
> library(stringr)
> text <- c("Senator, 1.4balbal", "rule 46.1, declares", "Town, 24", "A Town with a Long Name, 23", "THIS IS A DOCUMENT,23")
> towns <- unlist(str_extract_all(text, "\\b\\p{Lu}[^,]++(?=, \\d)"))
> towns
[1] "Senator"                 "Town"                   
[3] "A Town with a Long Name"
```

The regex matches:

- `\\b` - a leading word boundary
- `\\p{Lu}` - an uppercase letter
- `[^,]++` - 1+ chars other than a `,` (possessively, due to `++` quantifier, with no backtracking into this pattern for a more efficient matching)
- `(?=, \\d)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `,`, then a space and then any digit to appear immediately after the last non-`,` symbol matched with `[^,]++`.

Note you may get the same results with base R using the same regex with a PCRE option enabled:

```
> towns_baseR <- unlist(regmatches(text, gregexpr("\\b\\p{Lu}[^,]++(?=, \\d)", text, perl=TRUE)))
> towns_baseR
[1] "Senator"                 "Town"                   
[3] "A Town with a Long Name"
>
```